A matrix sending a plane into a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$
Is a matrix $A:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which sends say a plane $x-2y-z=1$ into a point say $(1,-1,0)$ unique?
I've found the matrix which do the job, namely:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-2&-1\\
-1&2&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
I think the equation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=A(\vec{r}_T+s\vec{a}+t\vec{b}),$$ where $\vec{r}_T=(1,0,0)$, $\vec{a}=(1,0,1)$ and $\vec{b}=(2,1,0)$ span the plane, must hold for every $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$.
Could anyone help me with any advice?

Well, the zero matrix sends all planes to the same point, so if the destination point is free to be chosen, then uniqueness seems unlikely.

@EricTowers my read of the question is certainly not that the destination point is free to be chosen :)

@Malady : The use of "say" in "into a point say $(1,−1,0)$ ...", which should of course be in "into a point, say $(1,−1,0)$, ...", specifically muddies whether the point is pre-specified (i.e. before the matrix/-ces are chosen) or post-specified (i.e., after the matrix/-ces are chosen).

It is indeed unique. The reason being is that we have $3$ linearly independent points $p^1=(1,0,0)$, $p^2=(0,-\frac{1}{2},0)$, and $p^3=(0,0,-1)$ on that plane $x-2y-z=1$. Thus, given $Ap=(1,-1,0)$ for each point $p$ on the plane $x-2y-z=1$, we are given $A(p^i)$ for each of those $3$ linearly independent points $p^1,p^2,p^3$, namely $A(p^i)=(1,-1,0)$.
Indeed, if there were another matrix $A'$ such that $A'(p^i)=(1,-1,0)$ for each $i=1,2,3$, then that would give $(A'-A)p^i = (0,0,0)$ for each $i=1,2,3$, which would imply $A'-A$ is the zero matrix, due to the linear independence of $p^1,p^2,p^3$.

Let $P_1=(1,0,0)^T$, $P_2=(0,-\frac12,0)^T,$ $P_3=(0,0,-1)^T$ be three points on the given plane. $AP_i=(1,-1,0)^T$ determines $A$.
